# Fill the missing value using mode method comparing other column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Need to fill the missing value-using mode method(most frequently occuring value).

| Product | Another |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| A | Nan |
| A | Nan |
| B | 4 |
| B | 4 |
| B | Nan |
| B | Nan |
| c | 5 |
| C | 5 |

Output needs as below:

| Product | Another |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 4 |
| c | 5 |
| C | 5 |

If the product is A, the value should be 3 and for B, it is 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html). Note that there can be several modes, we take the first available one here:

```
df['Another'] = (df.groupby('Product')['Another']
                   .apply(lambda g: g.fillna(g.mode()[0], downcast='infer'))
                )
```

output:

```
  Product  Another
0       A        3
1       A        3
2       A        3
3       A        3
4       B        4
5       B        4
6       B        4
7       B        4
```

##### Alternative

If you expect a single valid value per group, use [`groupby.transform('first')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) instead:

```
df['Another'] = df.groupby('Product')['Another'].transform('first')
```

Comment: if i want to add manually how can it done? Like if i want to add value using fillna? take product A and add value 3 using fillna?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic. In any case this looks like a different question, maybe open a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```py
  import pandas as pd

  dict = {"Product":["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],   "Another" : 
  [3,3,None,None,4,4,None,None]}

  df  = pd.DataFrame(dict)
  null_data = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]

  mode = df['Another'].mode()

  df.loc[df.Product == "A", "Another"] = mode[0]
  df.loc[df.Product == "B", "Another"] = mode[1]
```